# JavaScript UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 encoding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a record i receive from a DB (encoded in UTF-8) that's external to my web app (ISO-8859-1 encoded).

My ajax script is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/get_transaction_history.php',        
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    dataType: 'JSON',                
    data: ({
        transaction_id: transaction_id
    }),
    success: function (response) {                    
        $("#table_tr_history tbody").remove();
        $("#table_tr_history thead").after("<tbody></tbody>");
        for (tr_change in response) {                       

            $("#table_tr_history tbody").append("<tr>" +
                "<td style=\"width: auto;\">" + decodeURIComponent(escape(response[tr_change]['user'])) + "</td>"  +
                "</tr>");
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have tried to make use of the `decodeURIComponent()` and `escape()` functions, but still my result is not displaying spanish characters correctly. For istance, it's displaying "IBAÿEZ" instead of the N with tilde in "IBAÑEZ", as it is stored in the DB.

I have not tried to change html encoding in my view, since this is data i'm receiving from an external application, which i cannot change. Moreover, the data printed on the screen is a 1-time occurence in only 1 view, being that the reason why i chose to decode it with a function and not reformulate the html.

Any input will be greatly appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: You should see exactly (one can use Fiddler) which bytes precisely arrive from your server: is it indeed IBAÑEZ in UTF-8 or not, and if yes, debug the javascript code (check each of the functions involved separately).

Comment: The ajax JSON response is:  "user":"IBA\u00c3\u00bfEZ"
\u00c3 -> Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE' (U+00C3)
\u00bf -> Unicode Character 'INVERTED QUESTION MARK' (U+00BF). I have no idea why that is.
BD Hex values, as per PL/SQL developer : 4942 41D1 455A (IBAÑEZ)

Comment: I never worked with PHP, but it appears that one has to understand what happens on the server. I would first check whether what you get from the db has the right encoding, and if yes, what happens with these bytes afterwards.

Comment: DB encoding is AL16UTF16, when querying "SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS"